# having issue with flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I m trying to delete the case records once they meet below condition in Flow.

Origin = Client Login AND
Created Date = Greater than 24 hours

Now for created date i am using :
1. Field : Created Date 
2. Operator : Greater than or equal 
3. Value : Create new Formula 
In which i used the resource FLOW and using "{!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}"

Please help me further to use "Created Date = Greater than 24 hours".
Thanks